# SDL writing text

Tags: c, text, sdl

I'm having a problem for a SDL project, I'd like to show text on the window and allow the user to input text. As much as I know, there is no simple way to achieve that. Do you hava any suggestion?
Note: I use C programming langage. I know there is a library called SDL_ttf which doesn't seems to make the job I want.

Answer (score 4):

I have to be honest, as I was reading your question, SDL_ttf immediately sprang to mind. It's not too hard to use and there are plenty of docs available.

What it sounds like you are looking for, is a library that provides a simple console interface, where your main programming interaction is to `write(...)` and `read(...)` text and it handles display, scrolling and so on.

This [project](http://code.google.com/p/srv-console/source/browse/trunk/SDLconsole.c?r=7) has a lot of code showing how to implement a simple 'console' in SDL, and it does use SDL_ttf to do so.

I'm not convinced you are going to avoid it, unless you grab someone's library that hides it away from you like [this one](http://wacha.ch/wiki/sdlconsole/) but you are going to have less control over the display and interactivity this provides.

Comment: Thank you for answering, 
Well, I'm making a simple physics engine that displays physical behaviours, and in my mind, there are two kinds of text for the project.

Text displayed. Example: The speed of the sphere, the coordinates of collisions.
Text inputted. Example: What is the width of the form.

So, some inputted text could be showed on the screen, and some other would just be a "scanf" taking instructions and doing the job, choosing a menu.

it's hard because some text using SDL_ttf makes sense, and it would be even more logical to write text directly from SDL...

Comment: Have a look at http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson23/index.php, it deals with reading text input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

I must go with [benosteen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790268/benosteen), SDL_ttf is a really good option. For my part, I used [this tutorial](http://gameprogrammingtutorials.blogspot.ca/2010/02/sdl-tutorial-series-part-6-displaying.html) to make it work in my project. It's really simple and straightforward.

**EDIT:**
I had some troubles with the Blending functionality of SDL_ttf, but I managed to make it work after [QuasarDonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428922/quasardonkey) found the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700085).

Have a look for a straight forward example on how to use it and create text surface.